# Not getting Html  Node value of a node that got using rss feed

Tags: android, html, rss

this is item element of rss feed

```
 - <item>
          <guid isPermaLink="false">40</guid> 
          <category>Parking</category> 
          <category>Paris - Charles de Gaulle</category> 
          <title>Quick drop-off</title> 
          <description><description>&lt;span style="color: #00437f;"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Trains &lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
SNCF mainline trains&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/strong&gt;The Paris-Charles de Gaulle SNCF station is situated between terminals 2C-2D and 2E-2F - The station is called "Aéroport Charles de Gaulle 2 - TGV".&#xD;
&lt;p&gt;Getting to or leaving Paris-Charles de Gaulle :&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
- Terminals ABCDEF - accessible via the travelator&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
-From Paris - Opéra to Paris-Charles de Gaulle&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
Stops at the airport :&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
- Terminals 2A, 2C, 2E-2F, 2D, 2B, 3 and 1&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
- Terminal 2G is linked to terminal 2C (entrance 4) by the free N2 shuttle &lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
(Average travel time : 15 minutes)&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
- Terminal 2G is linked to terminal 2C (entrance 4) by the free N2 shuttle &lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
(Average travel time : 15 minutes)&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
   Fare* : 15 € (Pass Navigo not valid)&#xD;
&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
 &lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
 6 bus lines between Tremblay en France, Goussainville, Sarcelles, Villiers le Bel, Othis, Villeparisis and Paris-Charles de Gaulle airport.&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
Fares* : Ticket t+, between 1,14 € and 2,28 €&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
&lt;div class="ll" style="border-top: #dadada 1px solid; ParaRoi=0&amp;amp;ParaProfiling=0&amp;amp;ParaCompte=Adp_mobile" /&gt; &#xD;
</description> 
          <pubDate>Tue, 01 Dec 2009 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate> 
          <enclosure url="http://services.aeroportsdeparis.fr/iPhoneRessources/pict_DpMinute.png" type="image/png" /> 
          <nbArticles>8</nbArticles> 
          <idSite>0</idSite> 
          </item>
```

I can access data of other nodes under that parent using Dom parser except description data.

using following function

```
    public class Rss_Data_Retriever 
{

    Document myDoc;
    private String[][] data=null;

    public Rss_Data_Retriever(String Url)
    {
        InputStream in;
        in=getInputStream(Url);
        myDoc=getDocument(in);

    }   
    public String getSampleString() 
    {
        String s=getNthNodeValue("category", this.myDoc,0);
        FeastingOfData(this.myDoc, "item");
        return s;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(String urlString) 
    {
        int responseCode=0;
        HttpURLConnection  httpurlConnection = null;

        try 
        {
            URL url=new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection;


            connection=url.openConnection();

            httpurlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)connection;

            responseCode=httpurlConnection.getResponseCode();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(responseCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {

            Log.d("Message", "httpOk");
            InputStream input_fn=null;
            try
            {
                input_fn = httpurlConnection.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return input_fn;

        }   
        else
            Log.d("Message", "httpNotOk");

        return null;

    }

    public Document getDocument(InputStream inputStream) 
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        NodeList docTitle = null;
        Document Doc=null;


            try 
            {
                builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                Doc= builder.parse(inputStream);
            }
            catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (FactoryConfigurationError e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return Doc;
    }

    public String getNthNodeValue(String Tag,Document doc,int index) 
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        NodeList docTitle = null;
        Document Doc=null;

        docTitle=doc.getElementsByTagName(Tag);


        builder=null;
        Doc=null;
        Element value=(Element) docTitle.item(index);
        return value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

    }
    public String getNthNodeValue(String Tag,Element element,int index,boolean isValue) 
    {

        NodeList nodeList = null;
        try         
        {


            nodeList=element.getElementsByTagName(Tag);
        }
        catch (FactoryConfigurationError e) 
        {

        }

        Element value=(Element) nodeList.item(index);
        if(isValue)
            return value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        else
            return value.getAttribute("url"); 
    }

    public String[][] getData() 
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void FeastingOfData(Document doc,String TagName) 
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        NodeList nodeList = null;




                nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName(TagName);
                Log.d("Message", "Length:"+nodeList.getLength());

                if(data==null)
                    data=new String [nodeList.getLength()][5];

                int i=0;

                for(i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++) 
                {
                    Element node=(Element) nodeList.item(i);
                    String maincategory=getNthNodeValue("category", node, 0,true);
                    String category=getNthNodeValue("category", node, 1,true);
                    String title=getNthNodeValue("title", node, 0,true);
                    String description=getNthNodeValue("description", node, 0,true);
                    String enclosureUrl=getNthNodeValue("enclosure", node, 0,false);


                    data[i][0]=maincategory;
                    data[i][1]=category;
                    data[i][2]=title;
                    data[i][3]=description;
                    data[i][4]=enclosureUrl;



                    Log.d("DataChecked", "maincategory:"+maincategory);
                    Log.d("DataChecked", "category:"+category);
                    Log.d("DataChecked", "title"+title);
                    Log.d("DataChecked", "enclosureUrl:"+enclosureUrl);
                    Log.d("DataChecked", "Description:"+description);
                }

    }
}
```

I tried to print node value of description then I got "<" simple only at the same time I can print 
categories,title etc.

what can be the problem

Regards,
Kariyachan

Comment: Can you please post your entire code of parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved Html contents is in *description* tags so I changed the code as follows.Now I can 
Load the string returned to webview.

Hope somebody will find this helpfull.

Thanks

```
public String getNthNodeValue(String Tag, Element element, int index,
            boolean isValue) {

        NodeList nodeList = null;
        try {

            nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(Tag);
        } catch (FactoryConfigurationError e) {

        }

        Element value = (Element) nodeList.item(index);
        if (Tag.equals("description")) {
            String str = "";
            value.normalize();
            str = value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            return str;
        }

        if (isValue)
            return value.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        else
            return value.getAttribute("url");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're description contains further xml/html markup but is not surrounded with a CDATA declaration. My guess is that this is causing the parser to interpret the content as further markup rather then a node value. You can find a basic explanation of CDATA [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the reply.I updated my question with description data which is got from view source of that rss feed site .please have look thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the logcat output? You are just printing the stack trace when you hit exceptions, so I'm wondering if any of those are getting hit. Can you check if the description node has children?

Comment: I looked at logcat output i got **<** sign as  output and description has no child node.